# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field error while watcing in Eclipse debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Sometimes, when I am trying to watch variable inside inner classes, including anonymous, I can't do that.

Debugger says

```
<error(s)_during_the_evaluation>
```

and the text

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field myvariable
```

as a details.

The variable is not static and the reference is not static too.

If prepend variable name with `MyClass.this.` then it starts to display.

If I use myvariable in code with

```
log.info("var = {}", myvariable)
```

it also works.

So the problem is with Eclipse debugger only: it can't distinguish enclosing class variable from static one.

How to fix?

**UPDATE**

Language is Java.

Java is probably any.

Eclipse is Kepler and also probably any.

Code follows:

```
public class Try_Debug_01 {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Try_Debug_01.class);

    private int myvariable = 12;

    private Object object1 = new Object() {
        {
            log.info("var = {}", myvariable);

            new Object() {
                {
                    log.info("var = {}", myvariable);
                }
            };
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Try_Debug_01();
    }

}
```

proof:

[image]

Comment: Not enough details.  You will need to reduce this down to the smallest possible example that reproduces the problem so others can elicit the same behavior.  What version of Eclipse?

Comment: And/or show us the source and what language this is.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you add a "watch expression" maybe you want replace your expression by

```
this.myvariable
```

Comment: `this.myvariable` means something different; sample works if `Try_Debug_01.this.myvariable`

Comment: Can you tell me if is visible on the variables tab?